# What can go in the "value" portion of the PHP array() construct?

Tags: php, arrays

The PHP documentation says that array() is not a function, but a language construct. Empty(), another language construct can only test if variables are empty, not expressions.  Does array() have any limitations like that?  The documentation carefully explains what can go in an index, but seems to be vague about the value.

I did some tests and it does accept simple expressions.  The following works fine:

```
$a = "one";
$b = "two";
$c = "three";
$testit = array( "first element"=>$a, 'second element'=>$a.$b, 'third element'=>"$a $b $c" );
```

Could the value clause of the array language construct be a function or any valid expression?

Answer (score 2):

Array elements can hold any value, just like any other variable in PHP. It can even contain other arrays.

The index howover, must be composed by numbers and strings only. Objects, resources or other arrays cannot be used as index.

Comment: .. "Could the value be a function or any valid expression?" -no

Comment: Actually, I believe it can.

Comment: @Dagon yes, as of PHP 5.3 which introduced [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: haven't caught up up with html5 let alone php 5.3 ;-)

Comment: I understand that array elements can hold any value. What I am asking is, can the array "function" take any expression in the value clause?

Comment: Any expression that can be assigned to any regular variable, yes. Naturally you cannot declare a Class inside it, the same way you cannot declare a Class to a variable.